# opening a PDF incompletely in CHROME

Tags: c#, google-chrome, pdf

I tried to get a pdf file opened in chrome but it seems to be stuck in the middle of somewhere during displaying process. The code seems to work because it can get PDF opened in IE, not sure why it got stuck in chrome. The screen will just grey out, show the "LOADING" sign, and stop at 7/8. The file is around 6MB or more.

```
    public static void ReturnPDF(byte[] contents)
    {
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        response.Clear();
        response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + "abc.pdf");

        response.BufferOutput = true;
        response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
        response.BinaryWrite(contents);

        response.Flush();
        response.Close();

        response.End();
    }
```

Any thoughts? Thanks

[UPDATE]

I tried firefox with version 30.0 and it WORKS. My IE is 8.0.7601.17514, which can also open pdf. My Chrome is 39.0.2171.95. Not sure wheather the version of the browser matters or not, here only chrome fails to open the inline PDF...

[SOLVED]

After adding content-length, chrome can open the inline PDF.

```
   public static void ReturnPDF(byte[] contents)
    {
        var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        response.Clear();
        response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + "abc.pdf");

        //After adding Content-Length, chrome is able to open PDF inline
        response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", contents.Length.ToString());

        response.BufferOutput = true;
        response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
        response.BinaryWrite(contents);

        response.Flush();
        response.Close();

        response.End();
    }
```

Comment: You don't transmit the content length in a header. Some viewers don't like that.

Comment: @mkl You are right. After I added the content length, chrome can finally open without any issues. Thanks

Comment: @mkl can you post your answer below so I can give you the credits. thanks

Comment: You edited the solution into your question. It would be better if the question essentially remained a question including backgrounds and your answer included the solution. If you prefer, I can answer instead.

Comment: @mkl, Thanks for your suggestions. I made the corresponding change and please leave your answer below. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP's original code created the response like this:

```
response.Clear();
response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + "abc.pdf");
response.BufferOutput = true;
response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf;
response.BinaryWrite(contents);
response.End();
```

This code especially does not set the **Content-Length** header. Some web browser versions (not only Chrome but also certain versions of other browsers) without that header tend to prematurely consider the download finished.

Detecting when a download is finished on a connection initially created as persistent, may not be trivial if neither a non-identity **Transfer-Encoding** nor a **Content-Length** has been supplied.

Thus, the solution here is to add

```
response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", contents.Length.ToString());
```

before writing the `contents`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with "Content-disposition: attachment" header.

Comment: This will get the pdf forced downloaded. What i want it here is to get it forced Open in the browser, so I used inline. It can open the pdf in IE but got stuck in chrome while opening

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mkl's suggestions.

I added the content length in the header and the pdf can be successfully opened in Chrome!